# Beautifulsoup parse not working

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am trying to parse the url from movie poster website, but it keep returning an empty array.

```
htmltext = (urllib.urlopen("http://www.movieposterdb.com/Movie/"+str(ID))).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmltext, 'html.parser')
links = soup.find("a", { "class" : "mpdb-movie-thumbnails-img-link" })
print links
```

and the html source looks like this

```
<a class="mpdb-movie-thumbnails-img-link" href="javascript:ShowPoster('87a25cbd');"><img class="mpdb-movie-thumbnails-img" title="The Joneses Poster" src="/img/posters/11_05/1972/68646/t_68646_87a25cbd.jpg" alt=""></a>
```

It should at least return something...

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `"mpdb-movie-thumbnails-img"` instead of `"mpdb-movie-thumbnails-img-link"`, then?

Comment: sorry I did not specify the "class", I have revised the question

Comment: The link is javascript.  I don't think BS can resolve that.  Have you tried selenium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BeautifulSoup only grabs what's visible on the source of the page to use for parsing.  If you look at the source of any Movie page, you'll see that there *are* no `a` tags with that class - thus, your `soup.find_all` call returns an empty list.  Using selenium, I was able to grab the `img` tags like so:

```
from selenium import webdriver

link = 'http://www.movieposterdb.com/Movie/20684'

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get(link)
links = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('img')

for i in links:
    print i.get_attribute('src')
```

Now from here, you could filter it to just the movie poster link like so:

```
for i in links:
    if 'posters' in i.get_attribute('src'):
        print i.get_attribute('src')
```

Comment: Thanks. After i run "pip install selenium" in my current folder, it shows "ImportError: No module named selenium"?

Comment: what do you mean by run it in your current folder? if you're on windows, you need to open up `Run` and enter `python -m pip install selenium`

Comment: I use Mac, and I installed selenium through terminal.

Comment: well, that error indicates that you installed selenium on a Python installation that isn't the one you're using.  Are your environment variables set properly?

Comment: btw how do i modify the code so that firefox window will not be open when the code runs?

Comment: well, you can use `PhantomJS`, an excellent headless browser that works with selenium.